Are universal generalization, universal instantiation, existential generalization, and existential instantiation necessary?
Are all four rules of natural deduction necessary, or can we reduce them to just one?
1. Universal Generalization
P(α); therefore ∀x[P(x)], where α denotes an arbitrary individual.
2. Universal Instantiation
∀x[P(x)]; therefore P(α), where α denotes an arbitrary individual.
3. Existential Generalization
P(xn); therefore ∃x[P(x)], where xn denotes a specific individual.
4. Existential Instantiation
∃x[P(x)]; therefore P(xn), where xn denotes a specific individual.

Quantifiers generally are not necessary. There is no quantification in conditionals. In fact, quantification is just wrong. The expressions you ask about are purely theoretic consequences of a false theory. False theories are unnecessary.

No, they are not all necessary, you can get by with just Universal Instantiation.
Derived rule UG

Let α denote an arbitrary individual.
α=x1 and α= x2 and α=x3 and... [1; Df]
P(α)
P(x1) and P(x2) and P(x3) and... [2,3; sub]
∀x[P(x)] [4; Df]

Derived rule UI2
∀x[P(x)]; therefore P(xn), where xn denotes a specific individual.

∀x [P(x)]
P(x1) and... P(xn) and... [1; Df]
P(xn) [2; n applications of simp1]

Derived rule EG

If ∀x [¬P(x)] then ¬P(xn) [UI2]
If P(xn) then ¬∀x [¬P(x)] [1; prop. logic]
If P(xn) then ∃x [P(x)] [2; Df]
P(xn)
∃x [P(x)] [3,4; MP]


Derivations are wrong.

These are derived rules of inference, as opposed to underived rules of inference.  Why do you say derivations are wrong?

To derive e.g. Universal rules form Existential ones you have to assume the def of Exists as not Forall not and assume the premise of the Existential rule and derive the conclusion of the rule using the corresponding Universal rule, and others.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I didn't derive universal rules from existential ones.  I used the definition of the universal quantifier as an infinite conjunction, and some other definitions.
